# Antialiased JWindow (Shape)

Tags: java, graphics, shapes, antialiasing, jwindow

I have a JWindow in my application, it pops up at the upper right corner. I have set the shape to RoundRectangle2D, but the border of thw JWindow is not antialiased and therefore looks horrible. So my question is, how to I anti-alias a JWindow? I know how to anti-alias shapes with Graphics, but that does not work for the JWindow it self, does it? Anyway, how can I anti-alias the border of my JWindow?

Code:

public class Selector implements Interface {

```
//Variables
//Windows
    static JWindow Frame = new JWindow();

    static JWindow[] Label = new JWindow[100];

    static Shape Shape;

    static JWindow ExitWindow = new JWindow();

    static JWindow MenuWindowHide = new JWindow();

public static void initialize() {

    //Settings
    Frame.setBounds(0,0,(int)Utility.getScreenRes().getWidth(),(int)Utility.getScreenRes().getHeight());

    Frame.setOpacity(0.4f);


    ExitWindow.setBounds((int) (Utility.getScreenRes().getWidth() - 40), 25,20,20);

    ExitWindow.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    ExitWindow.setShape(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0,0,20,20, 6, 6));

    //Post settings
    Frame.setVisible(true);

    ExitWindow.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

To do this I will show how to make a JFrame with any shape that is anti-aliased.

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{

public MainFrame()
{
    setUndecorated(true);
    setBackground(new Color(0,255,0,0));
    setSize(300, 300);
    add(PaintingSurface); //Where PaintingSurface is JPanel with PaintPanel method below
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Then Add a JPanel that is the same size as the Frame and in its paint method draw the shpae you want with the following method

```
public void PaintPanel(Graphics g,Shape PaintArea)
{
    Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
    gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,  RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    gg.fill(PaintArea);
}
```